# How to parse the following with C# regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have this text: `"((FIELD1_NAME like 'Product%') And (Instr(FIELD1_NAME, 'Product_typ') = 1))";`

I would like to parse the `FIELD1_NAME` and `Product_typ` from the `Instr` part of the string.

This didn't work: `@"Instr((?<column>[A-Z0-9_]+), '(?<value>([^']|(''))+)'"`

Comment: You need a parser, not a regex. Whatever you do with regex right now is bound to remain a hack. Go for the real thing, write a simple recursive descent parser.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this `([^']|(''))+` ?

Comment: @sin - `'([^']|'')+'` matches a (non-empty) single quoted string, where a single quote is "escaped" by placing two in a row. (Similar to C#'s `@"..."` string style). i.e. it correctly parses strings encoded like this: `'that''s cool!'`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the first `(` after `Instr` and also make the group inside `value` group to non-capturing group,

```
Instr\((?<column>[A-Z0-9_]+),\s*'(?<value>(?:[^']|(''))+)'
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/hC4iP0/3)

Answer (score 0):

This regex uses dot-all on a lazy quantifiers to get the var's.
Mostly to trim and because you don't state it's for validation.

```
 # @"(?s)Instr\s*\(\s*(?<feild>.*?)\s*,\s*'\s*(?<prodtype>.*?)\s*'\s*\)"

 (?s)
 Instr
 \s* 
 \(
 \s* 
 (?<feild> .*? )               #_(1)         
 \s* , \s* 
 '
 \s* 
 (?<prodtype> .*? )            #_(2)         
 \s* 
 '
 \s* 
 \)
```